# UITableView Not Loading Data Initially

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

My `UITableViewController`, when initially viewed does not contain any data. However once, I go to another `UIViewController`, the data appears while the segue is still animating, and then the data is there. So to actually see the data, I need to go to another ViewController, and then back to the `UITableViewController`. I am using the Parse.com framework. The following code, is of the initial `ViewController`, which is also a `UITableViewController` that segues the the `UITableViewController` that does not contain any data initially. Thanks for the help, I am a newbie at IOS development, so please make answers in swift.
 EDIT:Many of the answers or comments assume that the data is retrieved, and is just not loading unto the `UITableViewController`. However the problem is the fact that the data has not been retrieved by the time the segue has been completed. Thanks

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?){
    var cell = sender as UITableViewCell
    var text = cell.textLabel!.text
    currentScreen=text!
    println(currentScreen)
    groupConversation=[]
    var messageDisplayOne = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
    messageDisplayOne.selectKeys(["userPost"])
    messageDisplayOne.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
            for object in objects {
                var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
                groupConversation.append(textObject)

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling [tableview reloadData] in viewDidAppear.

Comment: @rakeshbs would that look like `tableview.reloadData` in swift?

Comment: yes. tableview.reloadData in swift

Comment: @rakeshbs I just tried it out, but unfortunately, I still have the same problem, because all the data has not loaded by the time the `UITableViewController` appears.

Comment: do u have a call back when all the data has been loaded? add a reload call when the loading of data is done.

Comment: @rakeshbs Could you tell me how to do that, I'm new to IOS. Thanks

Comment: Rakeshbs technique should work. Use tableview.reloadData in the success callback of your query. So it should go right after your for loop

Comment: how are you loading the data? is it from a db? or downloaded?

Comment: @rakeshbs The data is from Parse.com, so it is from a database.

Comment: @PatrickBradshaw the code I have posted is from the initial view controller, not of the one that is not loading Data, so I don't think using tableview.reload data in the success callback of my query would work.

Comment: Ahh, didn't think about that. Ignore my answer for the moment and I'll update it in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you segueing into a UITableViewController?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:AnyObject?){
    //Start Spinner
    var cell = sender as UITableViewCell
    var text = cell.textLabel!.text
    currentScreen=text!
    println(currentScreen)
    groupConversation=[]
    var messageDisplayOne = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
    messageDisplayOne.selectKeys(["userPost"])
    messageDisplayOne.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
          //Stop Spinner
          if error == nil{
            println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
            for object in objects {
                var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
                groupConversation.append(textObject)

            }
            var tableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController
            tableViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am segueing into a UITableViewController.

Comment: Well I was just typing this into my own answer, haha. You can grab the table view controller this way (through destinationViewController) and reload it from there. The only other thing you may (not sure) need to do would be to unwrap the segue, which you could do by replacing segue: UIStoryboardSegue with segue: UIStoryboardSegue! in your method header

Comment: On the line that contains `tableViewController.tableView.reloadData` i get an error stating that "expression resolves to unused function."

Comment: try adding parentheses () to reloadData. I'm not well versed in swift (I main Objective-C) but a quick search told me that they were required since it is a method and not a property

Comment: @PatrickBradshaw I don't think the problem is that the `UITableViewController` is not updating the data but rather that the problem is the fact that the data has not been retrieved by the time the segue has been completed. So maybe a spinner would work?

Comment: that is why we are reloading the data after the data has been downloaded inside the block.

Comment: yeah I completely missed the () for the function. Got it confused with Ruby.

Comment: @rakeshbs ahh ok. I just tried your answer out with parenthesis, and it works great. Out of curiosity, when there is more much more data, would it be better to use a spinner.

Comment: yes. Its good to use an activity indicator (spinner) processing is going on. u can also use a network activity indicator. like this http://ios-sdk.blogspot.in/2012/01/displaying-network-activity-indicator.html

Comment: @rakeshbs How would I accomplish using a spinner, since that was what I was going for intially?

Comment: i have added the comments in the places to stop and start the spinner in the above code.

Comment: @rakeshbs I know how to make the spinner, but how would I know when the data is done loading from Parse?

Comment: Did you see the places I put the comments? Start Spinner and Stop spinner. The data starts downloading when you call messageDisplayOne.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. It stops when you enter the block(at the stop spinner comment)

Comment: Could you please mark as answer if it solved your initial problem.

Comment: @rakeshbs How would I make the spinner in the `UITableViewController` that is segued into?

Comment: for that you will have to restructure your code move the downloader code to the uitableviewcontroller. Or start a spinner on viewDidLoad and stop with a function call into the uitableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

As Rakeshbs was saying in the comments, what is happening here is that your query is being executed on a background thread. That means that your view is loading before the query returns and executes its callback (loading in the data).

To account for this, we can use tableview.reloadData at the end of the success callback to reload the table once we have processed the data. Code below:

*NOTE: See Rakeshbs answer for a cleaner version, the only difference here is that I unwrapped the UIStoryboardSegue because it was known to cause issues when unwrapped when accessing properties in some cases.*

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:AnyObject?){
    var cell = sender as UITableViewCell
    var text = cell.textLabel!.text
    currentScreen=text!
    println(currentScreen)
    groupConversation=[]
    var messageDisplayOne = PFQuery(className:currentScreen)
    messageDisplayOne.selectKeys(["userPost"])
    messageDisplayOne.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
                println("Type message \(groupConversation)")
            for object in objects {
                var textObject = object["userPost"] as String
                groupConversation.append(textObject)

            }
            var destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController
            destinationController.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }
    }
}
```